# Call Bootstrap function from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Am try to call angular-js function but it says " Cannot read property 'forget' of undefined" please help to resolve this

am using following js code

```
var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp', ['firstApp','secondApp']);

var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
  alert("First app ");
});

var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', []);
secondApp.controller('SecondController', function($scope) {
  alert("Second app. ");

 $scope.forget = function () {
 alert("forget function calling ");

 }

});
```

and in html i used following line to call this function.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('SecondController')).scope().forget();
```

Comment: I guess `SecondController` is not the ID of the element, try `angular.element(document.querySelector('[controller="SecondController"]')).scope().forget();`

Comment: it's says  Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: i used following line but still it's says same angular.element(document.querySelector('[controller="SecondController"]')).scope().forget();

Comment: why are you using it like this... there must be better way of doing it.. can you share the detail as to where you are using it and post code around it

Comment: am new to this domain.i am trying to call different services,for login action and forgot password action.and am using bootstrap also. it there any better way? is thr any example or methodology for this ?

Comment: This is really not the angular way at all.  you haven't shown enough of your HTML to really understand what you are trying to do, but using `document.getElementById` to call an angular function is completely outside the angular methodology.

Answer (score 0):

put this code inside a controller

```
$scope.forget = function () {
   alert("forget function calling ");
}
```

Comment: If you look closely, `SecondController` already have a function `forgot`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to have some id to the DIV where you used ng- controller='SecondController'.
For example,

```
<div id="controllerContainer" ng-controller='SecondController'>
</div>
```

And then used the following code to call the function:

```
var $scope = angular.element($('#controllerContainer')).scope();
$scope.forget();
$scope.$apply();
```

I have used jQuery selector but you can try with plain javascript selectors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the scope via jQuery selector is kind of a hack way to do it. You want to split your page into logical sections and define a controller for each one like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="forget()">Forget</button>
</div>
```

DOM elements inside the div will have access to `MainCtrl`'s scope, so only thing left to do is define the function inside your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.forget = function forget() {
        // insert forget logic here
    }
}]);
```

Notice the array notation used to define the controller. This is important if you want to minify your code, because angular relies heavily on dependency string values. Here's a [sample plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9MfDJwsYN5M19sHyDXnd?p=preview) for you to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what you are exactly trying to do but Angular work different way. I guess you are trying to call "forget()" on load of your DOM. If this is a case then you are doing on wrong way.

Wrong Approach
angular.element(document.getElementById('SecondController')).scope().forget();

Best Approach

```
            var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp', ['firstApp', 'secondApp']);

            var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
            firstApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope) {
                alert("First app ");
            });

            var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', []);
            secondApp.controller('SecondController', function ($scope) {
                alert("Second app. ");
                $scope.forget = function () {
                    alert("forget function calling ");
                }

                init();

                function init() {
                    $scope.forget();
                }
            });
```

> Otherwise if you are trying to call this "forget" method on button click or something then you need follow below approach.

```
        <div id="controllerContainer" ng-controller='SecondController'>
           <input type='button' ng-click='forget()' value='Click me'>
         </div>
```